# TestSubmitFramesWhenInDash Test FAILED

Tags: validation, store, publish, virtual-reality, oculus

I am trying to pass the virtual reallity checks in order to publish an App on the Oculus Store, but unfortunatelly I get the test "TestSubmitFramesWhenInDash" failed.

```
Starting TestSubmitFramesWhenInDash
Waiting for the application to run for 5 seconds before testing begins...
Starting test...
Testing for focus aware app.
Showing dash...
Number of texture swap chains committed when visible 0
Number of texture swap chains committed when not visible 0
ERROR: Focus aware app failed to commit to texture swap chain when dash was shown.
Please refer to VRC Guidelines: https://developer.oculus.com/distribute/latest/concepts/vrc-pc-input-9/
Cleaning up...
Test FAILED
```

What can I do to pass this test?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this issue using the Oculus Integration package that comes with Unity,
I moved to the "Oculus XR Plugin", but got other tests failed like "TestSubmitFramesWhenNotVisible" or "TestAppShouldQuit",
but I found that the results of the "VRC Validator" are not so accurate,
then I submitted the App for review and passed the test.
My App was published without any problem.